# How to show such that the indicator's current value is greater than previous indicator value?

Tags: pine-script

New to language.
I would like to know the stochastic lines if it is pointing upward or downward (greater or lesser value than the previous candle bar.) Like if last candle bar the stochastic gold value is 25, I want it to show me if it 25> in the current realtime candle bar, it doesn't matter if it is repainted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hallo Arch and welcome to Pine Script. This is a script that changes the color on the line if the current stochastic value is greater than the previous value.
[image: stoch graph with color lines]

To get the stochastic timestamp you to like this:

```
sto = ta.stoch(close, high, low, length)
```

To get the previous stoch value you do like this:

```
sto[1]
```

to change the color of the line, you can write this:

```
stoColor = sto[0] > sto[1] ? color.green : color.red
plot(sto, color=stoColor, linewidth=2)
```

This is called a "ternary if statement". So if `sto[0] > sto[1]` is true the `stoColor` variable will become color.green. if the statement is false the `stoColor` will become color.red.

Full Script:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © CanYouCatchMe

//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=10, minval=0, maxval=100)
sto = ta.stoch(close, high, low, length)

//sto[1] means value on one bar back
//if current > last is true, then stoColor = color.green. Else stoColor = color.red
stoColor = sto[0] > sto[1] ? color.green : color.red

plot(sto, color=stoColor, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thank you! How would one code without using 'Else'? I ought to separate the result "if sto[0] > stop[1]" turns false, with the stochastic value "if sto[0] = stop[1]" as another color as well as "if sto[0] < stop[1]". I only found the nested if statement: if inside another if or else code.

Comment: You can write this `stoColor = sto[0] > sto[1] ? color.green : sto[0] == sto[1] ? color.orange : color.red` so if sto[0] and sto[1] are the same, the color becomes orange.